# DNS Overwrite for a single domain

Tags: domain-name-system, mac-osx

I am running on a Mac.  I volunteer at a local church.  I created a site to site VPN so that I can monitor their traffic and other resources.  When I am at the local church, I am unable to connect back to my home network via my local domain "mydomain.local".  I am able reach the resources via its IP, but not through the FQDN.  Is there a way that I can do a DNS override on my Mac to tell it that any traffic from "X.mydomain.local" go to DNS server 192.168.1.1?  I don't want to send all the church's DNS traffic to my local DNS server just my laptop for this specific domain, all other traffic should go out the normal global DNS.

Comment: **I created a site to site VPN so that I can monitor their traffic and other resources.** - This is a bad idea, for you and for them. If you need/want to monitor their resources look into using one of the plethora of commercially and/or FOSS available solutions. Many commercial solutions have a "free" tier.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not. The fact that you're using `.local` and mention Mac indicates that it's not DNS; it's mDNS. That's based on multicast/broadcast.

You *could* theoretically set up some kind of bonjour/multicast proxy, but it's probably not the correct way to solve your problem. To me this sounds more like an X-Y problem.

The fact that you want to mix your home network into another network is somewhat of an red flag to me. You should *probably* reconsider your architecture so that there's more separation between the networks.

Answer (score 0):

I found a working solution.  [Unbound](https://unbound.docs.nlnetlabs.nl/en/latest/)